# Cannot block defective AMD GPU and enter Ubuntu with KVM, plus GRUB won't show up

Tags: grub2, uefi, radeon, kvm-virtualization

I've installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 on an old laptop whose AMD Radeon GPU is dead. I disabled the GPU by adding "radeon.modeset=0" into GRUB default bootup option to prevent computer display from freezing at startup.

Now I've just installed KVM and updated kernel to use virtual machine. Yet after installation and reboot the computer freezes again after bootup. I've tried updating GRUB again with Live-USB but it didn't help. I've also tried to let Ubuntu show GRUB at startup by changing "GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden" to "=menu" but GRUB menu still won't show up.

What shall I do to disable GPU for KVM and enable Grub?

Comment: Can you disable it in the BIOS?

Comment: No. It will be much easier otherwise.

Comment: You said "Now I've just installed KVM and updated kernel", but since KVM isn't a package and a kernel update not strictly necessary as any Ubuntu kernel would do could you extend your post with the details what you installed and what you upgrade from version A to version B? For grub I think you also need to bump the timeout GRUB_TIMEOUT to have a better chance.